# how to save the value of a jspinner from change listener

Tags: eclipse, swing, jspinner, jform-designer, changelistener

I wish to use the value created called spinnerModel but cannot seem to do so, I believe I have to declare it as a certain type which I am not sure. I want to make it into a double as it will be used later in the program.
I have the following as it stands,

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

 public class UI  {

 //Need to use the spinnerModel here but cannot :(

private void weightSpinnerMetricStateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    JSpinner weightSpinnerMetric = (JSpinner) e.getSource();
    SpinnerModel spinnerModel = weightSpinnerMetric.getModel();
    System.out.println(spinnerModel.getValue());
}
    stonesSpinnerImperial = new JSpinner(); //Spinner created here.

stonesSpinnerImperial.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(3, 3, 31, 1));
            stonesSpinnerImperial.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                    stonesSpinnerStateChanged(e);
                    stonesSpinnerImperialStateChanged(e);
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should retrieve the value from the spinner model, and not trying to save the event.

This is all explained in the [Swing tutorial about spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html). A small copy paste of the code from that turial

```
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        SpinnerModel dateModel = dateSpinner.getModel();
        if (dateModel instanceof SpinnerDateModel) {
            setSeasonalColor(((SpinnerDateModel)dateModel).getDate());
}
```

Of course you will need to adjust this code to match your current setup (e.g. change the cast to `SpinnerDataModel` to your spinner model)

Comment: I was wondering as I am using numbers if using the SpinnerNumberModel would be any better? If so how would you use it or is it the same as the SpinnerDataModel?

Comment: What exactly is still a problem. As you set the model yourself, you can safely cast is to `SpinnerNumberModel`